# C2D_MESSAGE permission error?

Tags: android

This seems to be a fairly common question without a good answer. I've just followed the google guide for GCM push messaging and am getting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eric.bander.app/eric.bander.app.MenuScreen}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission eric.bander.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission eric.bander.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(GCMRegistrar.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at eric.bander.app.MenuScreen.onCreate(MenuScreen.java:43)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4469)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
E/AndroidRuntime(21779): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission android:name="eric.bander.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"  android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="eric.bander.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="eric.bander.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This is the piece of code in MainMenu:

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
if (regId.equals("")) {
  GCMRegistrar.register(this, "808426403545");
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And I don't know if its relevant but my app strucutre is like this with the GCM intent service in another package:

```
eric.bander
         -MainMenu.class
eric.bander.misc
         -GCMIntentService.class
```

I hope someone can help with this, always frustrating when you are following a tutorial.

TIA

Comment: I had with the same problem, when my GCM intent class in another package. i just moved GCM intent in main package whateve package i used in maniefest.and its worked fine for me.

Comment: Just what I did and its working. Although I've now got a different error saying empty constructor!

Comment: Thanks, its all working now.

Comment: Just a heads up. The "Empty Constructor" error is given when you dont have an empty constructor when you use mulitple constructors in your class. The constructors with the parameter should also call `super`

Comment: This happens for some devices, sometimes. For the absolut majority, this is not a problem. But sometimes it happens, and Im not sure why... and its not a package name issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My error was having GCMIntentService in a different package to the class that registered the GCM.